# Copying the DVD contents to HDD and installing GTA V?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

Did anyone try copying the DVD contents to a folder on HDD and installing from it?

Does it work?

I have the DVD version. Copying 7 DVDs now. My Gaming Desktop doesn't have a DVD drive. I am copying the DVD to folder on laptop.

What options do i have?

Comment: search for a Program to make an iso (e.g. Power Isohttp://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/iso-maker.htm). Later on you can mount the iso with clone drive (or similiar).

Comment: @LosKartoflos: Note that Windows 8 has native .iso support, you no longer need specific tools for it.

Comment: okay. I'm still ond w7 :D

Answer (score 5):

**YES**

https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/communities/public/questions/203460387-Feature-transfer-error

According to discussion on this link, it is possible.

> I fixed my installation issue by copying the DVD files to a harddrive
> and then installing from the HDD. It was about 5 times faster and
> without fail. If you're unable to transfer the files from DVD then
> it's probably a damaged disk.
>
> by WinduWaka

---

**Suggestion**
When copying pause midway and let the disk cool down. It worked for me because when I did a continuous copy, there were errors.

Copying files from the 7 DVDs to one single folder will make installing easier. No more browse and select DVD or folder 6 times per install.

Comment: Please consider including some of the relevant discussion in your answer, in case that thread is ever deleted.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop has access to the internet you can also download it. It's a big download but it's an option. I tried copying the DVDs to my PC but one of them wouldn't read so I had to download the whole game.
You can download it [here](https://socialclub.rockstargames.com/activate)

Comment: Slow internet speed dear. And a metered connection.